# Voltage live to neutral low

Tags: low-voltage, voltage

I'm in the uk on 240V. I've got an extractor fan that isn't working. What I find is that at the fan and the switch that operates it, live to neutral is 160V. Ground to live reads 240 and ground to neutral reads just a couple. This is with the fan disconnected. The rest of the house is fine - it's just the fan. I presume that it runs off the light circuit which reads as expected.

Anyone any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: You probably have a loose connection someplace on the neutral in your circuit. All connections are supposed to be accessible, so first check the connections in your fan housing, then the switch that controls it. Best of luck from across the pond!

Comment: I would agree with a loose wire, might check for a blown fuse, I have observed from answers a lot of equipment over there has local fuses.

Comment: Thanks guys - guess I'll get the screwdriver out and check those connections!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Like the guys said - a faulty connection on the neutral. This in a light fitting a few feet away.